# Revert tc back to original that existed before the tc command?

Tags: tc

I did this which worked great to limit my host's bandwidth.  But now I want to return to full speed. Sadly my command is not right.

```
ga@ga-EX58-UD4P:~$ sudo tc qdisc add dev eth1 ingress
[sudo] password for ga: 
ga@ga-EX58-UD4P:~$ sudo tc filter add dev eth1 root protocol ip u32 match u32 0 0 police rate 1mbit burst 10k flowid :1

ga@ga-EX58-UD4P:~$ sudo tc qdisc del dev eth1 root
[sudo] password for ga: 
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
```

What is the right command? Thanks so much

Comment: You should repeat the command with `add` changed to `del`.

Comment: ok which command? i have 2 commands shown. ty

Comment: Both of them? And in reverse order of which you ran them the first time to add them.

Comment: Well I already tried the 1st one alone, verbatim except add changed to del. It worked, seemingly.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Michael Hampton:

```
sudo tc qdisc del dev eth1 ingress
```

It seemed to work. The speed came back. Not sure if I need to run 2 commands though to restore fully in some way as MH recommended.